# Filling in dates/username automatically in JavaScript dialog box?

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I am trying to make a Javascript dialog box for use with a PDF stamp. For two of the fields, I want them to be automatically filled in with the current date and the username. These fields can then be edited by the user if necessary.

I'm not sure where to place that in the code, or if the syntax is correct.

[Pastebin to current version.](http://pastebin.com/eeXDkWAY)

This contains a variable called `dialog` that holds all of the fields and options for the dialog box.

Comment: Current date is not a big deal, but you should carefully read the notes to the identity property in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation. In order to use it you will need an application-level script which has to be installed on every machine whee this dialog is to be used.

Comment: The identity property is being correctly used, as far as I can tell.

Comment: There are security restrictions with this property; see documentation. You have access to this property only under specific conditions.